# ImageMagick - get optimal compression

Tags: image, resize, compression

I compared ImageMagick with other tools. In my example I just want to resize and compress images. The goal is an acceptable file size with good quality.

Original file size: **127 Kb**

**Comparison between ImageMagick and Caesium**

**Unscaled, quality set to 80%**

- ImageMagick: `convert image.jpg -strip -quality 80 optImage.jpg`
  => 123 Kb
- Casesium: 101 Kb

**Scaled to 640x359, quality set to 80%**

- ImageMagick: `convert image.jpg -strip -resize 640x359! -quality 80 optImage.jpg`
  => 48 Kb
- Caesium: 33.6 Kb

So what is wrong with that? Is there any ImageMagick-option I should include? Or is the quality parameter different between these tools?

**EDIT**: is there any Linux shell tool which is able to resize (maybe crop) and compress as good as Caesium?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that these quality-parameters are not the same; 80% quality on ImageMagick corresponds to 87% (not exact) in Caesium; to get a acceptable file size the ImageMagick quality-parameter should set to 80 (not losless). But I think it's not bad to use an extra losless compression for ImageMagick-resized images like jpegtran for JPGs and optiPNG for PNGs. They can reduce the file size a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an acceptable file size in mind, you can tell **ImageMagick** what it is and it will do its best to honour it.

Like this:

```
convert image.jpg -strip -define jpeg:extent=88kb optImage.jpg
```

---

If you want a way to do something similar with Python, I wrote an answer that works pretty well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621). It does a binary search for a JPEG quality that satisfies a maximum size requirement.