# How to reduce a jpeg size to a 'desired size'?

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library

In Python 3.x, I am using PIL to resize images, I know that we can reduce the height or width by subtraction or division by pixels. But, is it possible to resize an image to a desired size, say 200kb and remain its proportions? Assuming the image(s) is larger but the size is unknown.

Comment: It would be difficult/impossible to predict without performing the encoding. If you're prepared to encode you could then do a binary search.

Comment: You could bulk the file with garbage.

Comment: http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/jpegfit

Comment: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=628683

Comment: @PeterWood, what do you mean by bulk the file with garbage? Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: **ImageMagick** provides exactly that capability. You could *"shell out"* with a subprocess and use the commandline tools as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194093/2836621 Or you could jpeg encode to a bytesio buffer in memory with varying quality using a binary search without writing to disk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I am so confused here.. so there is no way I can use PIL to achieve this? And I did go through your suggestion on ImageMagick, and I was completely lost. Am I be able to use Jupyter notebook to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am still learning **Python**, so there may be better ways, but here is a function that saves a PIL/Pillow image as a JPEG and allows you to specify a maximum size.

It uses a binary search to minimise the amount of work needed and it encodes into `BytesIO` memory buffer to save writing images to disk. If anyone has any suggestions for improvements, please let me know!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import io
import math
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def JPEGSaveWithTargetSize(im, filename, target):
   """Save the image as JPEG with the given name at best quality that makes less than "target" bytes"""
   # Min and Max quality
   Qmin, Qmax = 25, 96
   # Highest acceptable quality found
   Qacc = -1
   while Qmin <= Qmax:
      m = math.floor((Qmin + Qmax) / 2)

      # Encode into memory and get size
      buffer = io.BytesIO()
      im.save(buffer, format="JPEG", quality=m)
      s = buffer.getbuffer().nbytes

      if s <= target:
         Qacc = m
         Qmin = m + 1
      elif s > target:
         Qmax = m - 1

   # Write to disk at the defined quality
   if Qacc > -1:
      im.save(filename, format="JPEG", quality=Qacc)
   else:
      print("ERROR: No acceptble quality factor found", file=sys.stderr)

################################################################################
# main
################################################################################

# Load sample image
im = Image.open('/Users/mark/sample/images/lena.png')

# Save at best quality under 100,000 bytes
JPEGSaveWithTargetSize(im, "result.jpg", 100000)
```

If I run that as is, with target size of 100,000 bytes, I get:

```
-rw-r--r--@   1 mark  staff     96835 11 Sep 18:21 result.jpg
```

If I change the target size to 50,000 bytes, I get:

```
-rw-r--r--@   1 mark  staff     49532 11 Sep 18:26 result.jpg
```

**Keywords:** Python, PIL, Pillow, JPEG, quality, quality setting, max size, maximum size, image, image processing, binary search.

Comment: I got an error from your else statement, "ERROR: No acceptble quality factor found" What did I do wrong?

Comment: I can't tell for sure without seeing your image and the target size you specified. If you tried to reduce, say, an 8,000x6,000 pixel image to 5,000 bytes it will have had difficulties. Please share your image and target size, or try increasing the target size to give it a better chance of success.

Comment: Can you clarify what size (in pixels) of image you tried to compress with this please and what target size you specified - because I have tried it successfully on many files.

Comment: sorry for my late response, may I know what IDE you're using? and what OS you're using? Thank you so much :)

Comment: I don't use an IDE, I just type the code into an editor (`vi`, not that it makes any difference) and save it and run it. I tested the code on a Mac and under debian. You know the formatting (indentation) is critical, don't you?