# Python: Size of grayscale numpy array after converting it to .jpg without saving to file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I have a `numpy` matrix with data of type `np.uint8` which I want to convert into a `.jpg` image without saving it as a file.

I want to be able to adjust the compression and to read the resulting size in bytes / bits of that `.jpg` file.

Is that possible?

So far I tried the following, but do not know how to adjust the compression and how to get the resulting size of the `.jpg` file:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np

n=100
I_np = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(n,n),dtype=np.uint8)
I = Image.fromarray(I_np)

with BytesIO() as f:
    I.save(f, format='JPEG')
```

Comment: I think this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621