# How to Resize the images to set particular Megabyte using Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-resizing, megabyte

I want to resize images by using Megabyte not by using resolution.
I tried the code below:

```
image =  Image.open(full_path)
image = image.resize((1900, 2400))
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
image.save(full_path)
```

The code which was return above works perfect but I need some thing like below

```
image =  Image.open(full_path)
if image>5Mb:
    image=image.resize(5Mb)
else:
    pass
image.save(full_path)
```

If Image size is less than 5 Mb that should save automatically and if Image size is greater than 5 Mb then it should be resized to 5 Mb and then save it automatically.

Is that possible to do as i said above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the internationally accepted SI abbreviations. MB=Megabyte https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte and Mb=Megabit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621