# How to display PIL Image dynamically

Tags: jinja2, python-imaging-library

I want to crop my image file using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) library and display it using Flask and Jinja.

I have tried this code:

```
@bp.route('/media/<fname>')
def fetch_media(fname):
...
    image = Image.open(path)
    cropped_image = image.crop(box)
    return cropped_image
```

This gives a TypeError:

> The view function did not return a valid response. The return type
>   must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable,
>   but it was a Image.

How can I return the Image to html page?

Comment: Not at a computer, but you need `cropped_image.save()` of type `PNG` into a BytesIO object and then return a `Response` of `bytesio.getvalue()` with MIME-type `image/png`

Comment: You can see the BytesIO aspect of saving an image to memory here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but certainly pretty close to this:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
from flask import Response

....
....
buffer = io.BytesIO()
cropped_image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
return Response(buffer.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: Yes, that is beatiful and works, thank you! Only there is missing `from flask import Response` clause from your example

Comment: I have added it in now - I was assuming you were familiar with all the `flask` stuff as you were already using it :-) Good luck with your project.