# How can I efficiently simulate image compression artifacts in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network

I'm training a neural net using simulated images, and one of the things that happens in real life is low quality JPEG compression.  It fuzzes up sharp edges in a particular way.  Does anyone have an efficient way to simulate these effects?  By that I mean create a corrupted version of a clean input. The images are grayscale, stored as numpy arrays.

Comment: Write them as low-quality JPEGs and read them back, maybe?

Comment: I'm considering that, perhaps writing to ramdisk.  The simulation is otherwise very fast, so I don't want to bottleneck it with a read/write to disk.

Comment: Have a look here to see how to write a JPEG to memory with `io.BytesIO` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621

Comment: It looks like I have a solution using imageio.imwrite() and imread(), plus io.BytesIO.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to write up an answer to your own question for all to see and refer to, then accept it as correct and bag the points... perfectly ok.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the answers in the comments, here is a solution which saves the image as JPEG and reads it back in, all in memory using standard python libraries.

```
import io
import imageio

# Image is 2D numpy array, q is quality 0-100
def jpegBlur(im,q):
  buf = io.BytesIO()
  imageio.imwrite(buf,im,format='jpg',quality=q)
  s = buf.getbuffer()
  return imageio.imread(s,format='jpg')
```

In my function I also pre- and post-scaled the image to convert from float64 to uint8 and back again, but this is the basic idea.