# How to use libjpeg to compress an image in python?

Tags: python, compression, libjpeg

I am using python to compress an image to varying degrees ( or quality ) . I have implemented it based on OpenCV:

```
def compressAndwrite(save_path, img, quality):
    '''
    save_path: string
    img: np.ndarray
    quality: int, 0-100
    '''
    cv2.imwrite(save_path, img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), quality])
```

Is there any way that I can use `libjpeg` in python to achieve the same effect instead of `PIL` or `OpenCV`?

If not, how can I compress and write an jpeg image using JPEG algorithm when given a parameter `quality`?

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to use OpenCV or PIL please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.
My ultimate goal is to compress an image to different degrees using JPEG algorithm.
 I have no idea how `cv2.imwrite` in OpenCV and `imObj.save` in PIL work to control the quality or compression ratio of the saved image relative to the original image. So I have to use `libjpeg` to do it.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621

Comment: This is the most comprehensive discussion of JPEG that I know https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPT4FSkFUgs